# Volcar registros uint16_t en una cadena

Tags: c, string

Buscaba una forma sencilla de convertir un array de elementos uint16_t a cadena.

Os pongo en situación. Tengo el array `uint16_t elementos[6];` que contiene en un momento dado de la ejecución los siguientes valores:

```
elementos[0] = 0x3132;
elementos[1] = 0x3334;
elementos[2] = 0x3536;
...
elementos[5] = 0x6263
```

Concretamente contiene la cadena "123456789abc" dividida en varios registros. Mi intención es poder representarla en un `char cadena[12];` de la forma en que os indicaba antes ("123456789abc").

No puedo usar `memcpy(cadena, elementos, 12);` porque esta función realiza una copia de memoria y por lo cual depende del endianess del equipo. Por ejemplo en mi caso está volcándola como "21436587a9cb".

Obviamente podría hacer un bucle e ir cargando los MSB en registros pares y los LSB en los impares, pero buscaba algo más elegante y sencillo como podría haber sido la memcpy.

Seguro que hay alguna función estándar que me lo hace en un paso y la he pasado por alto...

Una dificultad añadida es que si tuviera

```
elementos[0] = 0x3132;
elementos[1] = 0x3300;
elementos[2] = 0x0000;
...
elementos[5] = 0x0000;
```

tendría que obtener como resultado la cadena "123", terminando en el primer caracter nulo.

Gracias por adelantado.

Un saludo,

Areify

Answer (score 1):

Con un bucle puedes iterar a través de los 6 enteros. A continuación copias el valor en una buffer de tipo `char`. Para terminar, finalizas el buffer.

```
char cadena[13];
char * ptr = cadena;
for( int i=0; i<6; i++)
{
    *ptr++ = ((elementos[i] >> 8) & 0xFF);
    *ptr++ = (elementos[i] & 0xFF);
}

*ptr = '\0';
```

Comment: Este era el punto de partida, un bucle (con o sin el uso de un puntero auxiliar). De momento tampoco se me ha ocurrido otra cosa a mi tampoco. Muchas gracias!